# How do I dynamically include ouput from an external file?

Tags: theming

How do I dynamically include output from another web page?

This is the result of a CGI link along the lines of: http://www.example.com/name.cgi?Arg=argument  I would like to include everything within the html tags that it generates as HTML on my page.

(I own both web pages!)

Comment: This really sounds like a job for PHP's `file_get_contents()` (http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

Comment: If that doesn't work, `<iframe>`s come to mind.

Comment: use drupal_http_request(). Here is the link to documentation - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of modules that can help with this:

Web widgets (http://drupal.org/project/web_widgets): Embed any other web site content in a widget with a simple widget API.

Iframe_filter (http://drupal.org/project/iframe_filter): you just need to add this filter to an input format and the content you create using that format will be displayed inside an iframe created dynamically.

And other iframe projects: http://drupal.org/project/insertFrame, http://drupal.org/project/iframe_page (only dev version available right now for d7).